# Can I send variables to the same JavaScript from two pages?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, variables

I have 2 pages where the user gives data that needs to be stored (the 1st is a string from the first page and the rest comes from a form from the second page). This webpage is not on a server, its on a laptop without any connection to the internet. The plan is for all that data to be written on to a text document.

My question is; can I send the first variable to a JavaScript like `var = get.element...` and then redirect the user to the second page where more variables get sent to the same JavaScript without the first disappearing. Because from what I have understood, all the scripts and variables "reset" when reloaded.

***Extra, this is how I plan to write the info in a text file, does it look good or is there a better way to store data locally?***

```
<?php
function createFile(){
    $file = 'D:\test.txt';
    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    // Append a new person to the file
    $current .= "John Smith\n";
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
?>
```

Thanks for all your time!

Comment: Use local storage api from html5

Answer (score 1):

I would think to pass some parameters from the first page using `GET` or `POST` request to the second page.

For example:

```
//yourApp/second_page.php?name=John Smith
```

is requested from the first page so you can get the data in the second page using `$_GET['fname']`

The solution @shadow proposed (using html5 local storage api) seems more clean and simple tho.